# Jquery JQGrid - How to set alignment of grid header cells?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to align grid column headers in jqgrid?  eg align left right or center?

In the jqrid documents http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options it says:

```
align: Defines the alignment of the cell in the Body layer, not in header cell. 
Possible values: left, center, right.
```

Note that it says "not in the header cell".  How can I do this for the header cell (grid title cell)?  The documentation fails to mention this little detail....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best documented way to change column header alignment is the usage of `setLabel` method of jqGrid (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods).

You can change alignment of the column identified by `'name': 'Name'` with the following code:

```
grid.jqGrid ('setLabel', 'Name', '', {'text-align':'right'});
```

With the code

```
grid.jqGrid ('setLabel', 'Name', 'Product Name', {'text-align':'right'},
             {'title':'My ToolTip for the product name column header'});
```

you can change the header name to 'Product Name' and set 'My ToolTip for the product name column header' as a tool tip for the corresponding column header.

You can also define some classes in your CSS and set it for the column headers also with respect of `setLabel` method.

By the way the name of the function 'setLabel' is choosed because you can not define `colNames` parameter of the jqGrid, but use additional `'label'` option in the `colModel` to define a column header other as the `'name'` value.

**UPDATED**: You can do able to use classes to define `'text-align'` or `'padding'`. Just try following

```
.textalignright { text-align:right !important; }
.textalignleft { text-align:left  !important; }
.textalignright div { padding-right: 5px; }
.textalignleft div { padding-left: 5px; }
```

and

```
grid.jqGrid ('setLabel', 'Name', '', 'textalignright');
grid.jqGrid ('setLabel', 'Description', '', 'textalignleft');
```

(I defined 5px as the padding to see results better. You can choose the padding value which you will find better in your case).

Comment: Thanks - {'text-align':'right'} works, but I would prefer to use a css class.  Adding a css with .jqGrid('setLabel', 'Name', '', 'css-class-name'); didnt work - is that the wrong syntax?

Comment: Actually, { 'text-align': 'left' } places the header text too hard to the left: it touches the grid line.  I tried: { 'text-align': 'left', 'padding-left': '1px' }, but that moved the grid line at the end of the cell away by 1px as well.  I just want my headers to have the same alignment as the data cells.

Comment: @Jake: No, but you can use CSS only to do the same. If you have for example grid with the id of the `<table>` element as `'list'` and need to set alignment of the climn with the `name:'mycol'` you can use the fact that the <th> element will have the id="list_mycol". So you can define the corresponding CSS style without calling of `'setLabel'` method.

Comment: Hi Oleg, none of the code that you offered here works for me  - any other ideas how to justify the columns aside from good old css hack?

Answer (score 8):

Just go to your css file of your jqgrid.

Look for:

```
ui-th-column,.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column
{overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;text-align:center; ...
```

And change the text-align.

I didn't find it eather with regular options.

I hope this will help you.

Bruno

Comment: This will change the alignment of every header cell, which is not useful.  Need the headers to have the same alignment as the data cells.

Answer (score 3):

While using the 'setLabel' method seems feasible, I always want to have my header-cells aligned the same way as the cells.
So I just use this function:

```
function pimpHeader(gridObj) {
    var cm = gridObj.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    for (var i=0;i<cm.length;i++) {
        gridObj.jqGrid('setLabel', cm[i].name, '', 
            {'text-align': (cm[i].align || 'left')}, 
            (cm[i].titletext ? {'title': cm[i].titletext} : {}));
    }
}
```

This uses the alignment of the cells to align the header.
To be called like this:

```
pimpHeader(jQuery("#grid"));
```

If you want, you can extend your Column-Model with 'titletext', which is shown as a tooltip-header, like so:

```
colModel: [{ name: 'name', label: 'Name', align: 'right', titletext: 'Name-Tooltip'}, ...]
```

Comment: 5.5 years later and many thanks - this was perfect for a client using an older version of jqGrid!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
loadBeforeSend: function () {
    $(this).closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").find("table.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>tr>th").css("text-align", "left");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see the source to find out the css that your grid refer to
and then you can try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   jQuery('.ui-th-column').css('text-align','center');
},1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the **align** attribute to your Column in ColModel:

```
colModel: [
          {name: 'MyColumn', index: 'MyColumn', align: 'center'}
      ],
```