# jqGrid column is not aligned due to css confliction

Tags: css, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid. It works until I using a new plug in - jqxWidget. My problem is that the column of jqGrid is not aligned with the column header. Please see the following screenshot for more details.

[image: Wrong alignment]

Question: Is there any way to fix this issue ? 
I guess that CSS of jqxWidget affects the style of jqGrid. But I cannot find what it is exactly. Please give any idea if you see this issue before.

I tried to read it here: [jqGrid column not aligned with column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090255/jqgrid-column-not-aligned-with-column-headers), but I still cannot find the issue.

---

[Update 1]
I use free version of jqGrid, version 4.5.2. Date: 2013-05-21.

Comment: which version of jqGrid, [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=102666) or [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) you use? Could you provides the demo which reproduces the problem? Could you verify whether the same problem exists with free jqGrid? You can just replace (temporary) the urls of `ui.jqgrid.css`, `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` to URLs to CDN (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs))

Comment: Sorry, but if you use so old version of jqGrid and don't provide any demo which reproduces the problem then you have to solve the CSS conflict yourself. I added in CSS of free jqGrid many additional CSS rules which should solve the known conflicts. Probably the problem will be solved if you just use the new `ui.jqgrid.css`. If some new conflict exist I could localize it and fix in `ui.jqgrid.css` published on [github](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/tree/master/css), but analyzing of conflicts in one specific old version have really no value for other users.