# how to get the current sort column in a jqGrid after user clicks a column header

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm in the beforeRequest handler, and would like to know what the current sort column is. How can I find that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can examine the values of the jqGrid parameters `sortname` and `sortorder` ("desc" or "asc"). To get the parameters you can use `getGridParam` method:

```
var sortColumnName = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','sortname');
```

and

```
var sortOrder = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','sortorder'); // 'desc' or 'asc'
```

Comment: that's helpful, thanks. What I really want to do is add a class (either sortAsc or sortDesc) to the th of the sorted column.

Comment: @sprugman: What do you mean under "add a class ... to the sorted column."? Do you mean the column header or all cells in the column or both?

Comment: @Oleg: the <th> tags in the column header. I can write some code to do it with what you've given me. (In fact, I already have.) Just checking to see if there was something built in.

Comment: @sprugman: you can use `setLabel` method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003187/jquery-jqgrid-how-to-set-alignment-of-grid-header-cells/3006853#3006853 as an example.

Comment: Using the setLabel method, how do I unset the old class using that method? So, first time through, the first column gets the sort-asc class. Then I click on the third column. Col 1 needs to have sort-asc removed, while col 3 has it added....

Comment: @sprugman: A good point! You can't. Currently `setLabel` method use only `addClass` or `css` methods and no `removeClass`. So use have to do this manually. The `setLabel` method do following (see http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2904): It convert the name of the column to the column position if needed. Then it uses `var thecol = $("tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th:eq("+pos+")",$t.grid.hDiv);` to get the `<th>` element and finally calls `$(thecol).addClass(prop);` or `$(thecol).css(prop);`.  You can do the same to be most close to `setLabel` method but use `removeClass`.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the original sort name?  (not the current sort name).  Thanks!  (is this bad etiquette- asking questions in a comment? :))

Comment: @icats: Not a problem. I have enough reputation points which I can't use and I am not even a developer of jqGrid. I just help other people in my free file for the "thanks". So back to your question. You can use `$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','lastsort')` to get the **previous** sort order. What you mean under the "original sort name"?

Comment: @Oleg: thanks :).  By 'original' sort name I mean the sort name in the original grid options (sortname: "columnName").

Comment: @icats: You can save it somewhere at the first grid filling, in `loadComplete` for example. The code can be like `if (typeof myVarFirstSortName === 'undefined') { myVarFirstSortName = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','sortname'); }`