# jqGrid - extending for consistency

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to use jqGrid for a great many grids that have only a small set of application-specific column types, and I would like to create a way to enforce consistency. For example, I want all my columns that show the compliance status of a row to have a certain format, be aligned a certain way, have specific search options, etc. So instead of having a colmodel entry like this:

```
{ name: 'ABC', width: 80, align: 'center', stype: "select", 
              searchoptions: { value: "1:Compliant;0:Not Compliant"} }
```

I would like to have one like this:

```
{ name: 'ABC', width: 80, mytype: compliancestatus }
```

where compliancestatus is a function I would write.

Is this kind of thing possible - without modifying the jqGrid source code? If so, can someone point me to an example of this type of extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since jqGrid 3.8.2 are column templates supported.

You can just define for example

```
var compliancestatus = {
        width: 80,
        align: 'center',
        stype: "select", 
        searchoptions: { value: "1:Compliant;0:Not Compliant" }
    };
```

somewhere in the scope of visibility and then just use in `colModel`

```
{ name: 'ABC', template: compliancestatus }
```

In the template you can include any parameters. If the column definition has the same property but with the same value like

```
{ name: 'ABC', width: 100, template: compliancestatus }
```

the value from the `colModel` (`width: 100` in the case) will be used.

I [suggested](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/templates-for-columns-in-colmodel/#p20807) the feature some time before and I use it intensively myself. For example I have many grids having many columns with checkboxes. I use the following template in the case:

```
mySettings.templateCheckbox = {
    formatter: 'checkbox', align: 'center', width: 20,
    edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "1:0" },
    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ":Any;1:Yes;0:No" }
};
```

In the same way I defined many other templates which reduce the code of grids and improve managing of the common grid style.

If you want to change some common default settings *for all* columns you can use `cmTemplate` parameter of jqGrid. For example

```
cmTemplate: { align: 'center' }
```

You can use it as additional [parameter of jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) or set it like any other default parameter with respect of

```
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
    cmTemplate: { align: 'center' }
});
```

Read more about the column templates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044047/stopping-columns-resizable-in-jqgrid/6047856#6047856).

Comment: Perfect. I totally missed that.  Thank you.

Comment: I forgot something: With this in colmodel 
`{ name: 'ABC', template: compliancestatus }` 
I would also want to enforce consistency of the alignment of the column heading. What I think I have to do for the heading is to add this to the chain:
`.jqGrid("setLabel", "ABC", "", { "text-align": "center" })`
But even if I define alignment in a css class and do this:
`.jqGrid("setLabel", "ABC", "", "compliancestatusClass")`
this still requires me to set the alignment correctly in two places. Ideally there is an undocumented jqGrid option alignheadingswithdata:true`

Comment: @RonR: There are no property which can define the the alignment of the column headers. With respect of `setLabel` (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003187/jquery-jqgrid-how-to-set-alignment-of-grid-header-cells/3006853#3006853)) one can set the alignment. If you want you can enumerate `colModel` and set in the way the alignment of all column headers based on the alignment of the columns.

Comment: Thank you. That looks easy enough.