# how to using maskTextBox in jqgrid Add/Edit PopUp

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

i want create customText box in popup panel in jqgrid As follows:

4digit-3character-4digit

please help me. thanks

Comment: What you mean under "popup panel"? Do you use form editing? Do you want to have masked input field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [digitalBush](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) [masked jQuery plugin](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) for the editing. You should initialize the masked pluging inside of `dataInput` of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions)

```
dataInit: function (elem) {
    $(elem).mask("9999-aaa-9999");
}
```

Look [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MaskedInput.htm) and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8412707/315935) for more details.