# Build own $.mask.definitions for hours

Tags: javascript, mask, maskedinput

I´m trying to set a mask into a input text.

this is my code:

```
$.mask.definitions['H'] = '[012]';
$.mask.definitions['N'] = '[012345]';
$.mask.definitions['n'] = '[0123456789]';
$(elem).mask("Hn:Nn");
```

With this it can write 21:55 or 15:32, but it can write 29:45 too and it is wrong!!

What can i do?

Comment: Is this jQuery? Are those regular expressions?

Comment: Yes it is!
I am using in jqgrid column editoption definition..
And yes they are

Comment: Unfortunately I think jquery.maskedinput only looks at one character of the input at a time, so you're out of luck.  You want something like ([01][0-9]|2[0-4]) but that will never match one character.

Comment: I found this: 

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408104/jqgrid-mask-edit