# Do we need to validate the input in jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Does jqgrid has inbuilt validation? or Do we need to validate each and every values when user trying to do manipulating data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

One can define [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules) in `colModel` for validations. One can use `custom: true` property and [custom_func](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom_checking_example) callback for validation. The validation will be done *before saving modified data*.

One more possibility is the usage of plugins which you can initialize in `dataInit` callback (see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8412707/315935) as an example) of to register `change` event handler inside of `dataEvents`. It could allows to make validation *before* starting saving the data.

There are some other additional possibilities which are specific for editing mode. Form editing for example supports `beforeCheckValues` callback and `jqGridAddEditBeforeCheckValues` event which will be triggered before individual validation of editing fields and `beforeSubmit` callback and `jqGridAddEditBeforeSubmit` event allows to make additional final validation.

So you should just examine which possibilities more corresponds to your requirements.